# Centering a div to the viewport with other divs on both sides

Tags: html, css

I'm currently designing a header bar for a site I'm working on. I would like the header to show a logo at the left, the title in the center, and the user account on the right.

This mockup is what I'm envisioning. Note that the dotted boxes denote a div.

[image: Header Bar mockup]

I've made some progress on creating it in HTML/CSS, but I can't seem to get the title to center to the viewport.

[image: Current progress]

As you can see, the title is centering itself between the logo and the account info divs, instead of centering itself on the viewport. This ends up making the page just look a little bit off, and so I would really like to center the title to the viewport.

Here's my code:

```css
.headerBarArea {
    background-color: #7785A2;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;    
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.logoArea {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;

    border: lawngreen;
    border-style: dashed;
    border-width: 1px;
}

.minesLogo {
    width: 96px;
}

.titleArea {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;

    border: lawngreen;
    border-style: dashed;
    border-width: 1px;
}

.siteTitle {
    color: white;
}

.pageTitle {
    color: white;
}

.userAccountArea {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;

    border: lawngreen;
    border-style: dashed;
    border-width: 1px;
}

.userAccountIcon {
    float: left;
    width: 35px;
}

.userAccountText {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div className="headerBarArea">
    <div className="logoArea">
        <img src="assets/mines_logo_stacked.png" className="minesLogo" />
    </div>

    <div className="titleArea">
        <h2 className="siteTitle">This is my site Title</h2>
        <h3 className="pageTitle">Page Title</h3>
    </div>

    <div className="userAccountArea">
        <img src="assets/user_account.png" className="userAccountIcon" />
        <span className="UserAccountText">John Smith (Student)</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas on what I could do to make the title div centered **to the viewport**, instead of centering between the two divs?

Comment: try with adding `.titlearea {  position:absolute;
 left:50%;
 top:50%;}`  instead

Answer (score 2):

html code

```
   <div class="flex-container">
     <div class="flex-item">1</div>
     <div class="align-self-center">
        <span class="siteTitle">This is my site Title</span>
        <br>
        <div class="text-center ">Page Title</div>
     </div>
    <div class="flex-item align-self-end third-item">3</div>
   </div>
```

CSS code

```
  .flex-container {
  /* We first create a flex layout context */
  display: flex;

  /* Then we define the flow direction 
     and if we allow the items to wrap 
   * Remember this is the same as:
   * flex-direction: row;
   * flex-wrap: wrap;
   */
  flex-flow: row wrap;

  /* Then we define how is distributed the remaining space */
  justify-content: space-between;

}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.third-item {
  height: 100px;
}

.text-center{
  text-align: center;
}
.align-self-end{
  align-self:end;
}
.align-self-center{
  align-self:center;
}
```

code output

[image]

**code solution**

used flex to place the items used .flex-container as parent div where flex items are placed in .justify-content: space-between; is used to place space in between the items.  align-self:center; is used to place Page Title at center
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

**[codepen](https://codepen.io/Rishab24/pen/RwZRNON)**

Comment: Nice Effort. Well-designed example. Add some description in the answer as well.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to have the same behavior. If you add `width: 800px;` to `.third-item` in the CSS in your CodePen, you can see that the title is still centering between the divs, instead of centering on the viewport.

Comment: I have edited codepen code as per your needs please if this works for you.
https://codepen.io/Rishab24/pen/RwZRNON

Comment: I noticed that you added a `left: 50%` to the CSS. This aligns the left side to the center of the viewport, and I notice that when I shrink the browser narrow enough, the title is visibly not centered. However, this is the best solution I've seen so far, so maybe I'll just call it good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your css code with this to make title div centered in all the viewport.

```
.headerBarArea {
    background-color: #7785A2;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;    
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

}

.logoArea , .titleArea , .userAccountArea {
    border: lawngreen;
    border-style: dashed;
    border-width: 1px;
}

.minesLogo {
    width: 96px;
}

.titleArea {
    text-align: center;
   
}

.siteTitle , .pageTitle{
    color: white;
}


.userAccountIcon {
    float: left;
    width: 35px;
}

.userAccountText {
    float: right;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I changed out my CSS with the code you provided, and unfortunately it still has the same behavior.

Comment: Just have a look in screenshot i shared with you above. its working on my side.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood my question - I'm trying to position the title in the exact center of the browser viewport. In other words, I want the title to always remain in the exact center of the page, no matter how large the outer divs are.

Answer (score 0):

```
.headerBarArea{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center
}
```

It is an easy way to the layout.
you can try it.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to change the behavior at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding margin-left:auto; and margin-right:auto; to the .titleArea class .

I would suggest using a flex-box though.